# What are the three states of Yogi mentioned in Shvetashvatara Upanishad?

Tags: upanishads, yoga, samadhi

Shvetashvatara Upanishad 11<sup>th</sup> verse of 1<sup>st</sup> chapter:

> jñātvā devaṃ sarvapāśāpahāniḥ
>         kṣīṇaiḥ kleśairjanmamṛtyuprahāṇiḥ ।
>   tasyābhidhyānāt**tṛtīyaṃ** dehabhede
>         viśvaiśvaryaṃ kevala āptakāmaḥ ॥ 11॥
>
> I-11: With the knowledge of God, all fetters fall off. With the waning of ignorance, birth and death cease. Going beyond the consciousness of the body by meditating on Him, **one reaches the third state**, viz., the universal lordship. All his desires are satisfied, and he becomes one without a second.

It is mentioned that one reaches the third state and after then one attains Brahman. I want to know what is third state, more precisely what is meant by third state here and then consequently which three states are.

Comment: I would guess this third state is a reference to the third state of prajna mentioned in the Mandukya upanishad.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion  do you mean Sushupti?

Comment: Yes, this state corresponds to Ishwara, who has universal lordship. Both sushupti and turiya are non-dual states.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion Hmm. Btw, I am also looking for [Why is the state of shushupti (deep sleep) called prajnanaghana (mass of consciousness)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14222/277)

Comment: Shankara has an explanation for this. Please check - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mandukya-upanishad-karika-bhashya/d/doc143596.html

Comment: Please note - as per brihadaranyaka upanishad, deep sleep is as good as liberation. However, the other upanishads differ on this issue.